# Querying records from a table that contain a certain key/value in one of its columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the table `accounts` that stores several account preferences as a hash with key/value pairs in its `preferences` column.

`preferences` column stores data in the following way:

```
{
"accepts_coupons": true,
"accepted_coupon_types": ["percentage", "amount"],
"some_other_preference": [...],
}
```

How can I select accounts whose `accepted_coupon_types` contents contain the `percentage` value?

**For example** *(pseudo code)* `select * from accounts where accounts.preferences.some_key in ('some_value')` ?

I've tried something like this:

```
select name, preferences from accounts
where preferences in ('percentage')
```

but I'm getting `ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json, Detail: Token "percentage" is invalid.`

Is it possible to write a query that will look inside the column key/values to select the accounts that meet a certain value criteria in it's preferences column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
    select name, preferences
    from accounts
    where preferences ->> 'accepted_coupon_types' like '%percentage%'
```

db-fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cBsWdNZnmEjuaeZXT1yWju/0

Comment: Thank you. Why do I have to wrap the word in %% ?

Comment: It's a wildcard wrapper when using "like" operator. If you have both upper and mixed case, then you can change to "ilike".